# What do the keys on this Symbolics Space Cadet keyboard do?

Tags: keyboards, symbolics

Old keyboards like the one below seem to have contributed a lot to the design of modern keyboards. So, obviously, some of the keys are familiar because they are on my own average (modern Windows and Mac) keyboards, such as <kbd>space bar</kbd>, <kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>return</kbd>, and so on. Assuming that they do the same thing as the keys on modern keyboards, I don't need them explained.

But what do all the other keys do? And how would you type the other symbols (like <kbd>≥</kbd> and <kbd>¬</kbd>) on the main section of keys?

[image: strange keys]
<sup>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-cadet_keyboard</sup>

[image: key fronts]

<sup>https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Space-cadet-closeup.jpg</sup>

Comment: I found a description of most function keys of the space cadet in section 9 of *Operating the Lisp machine*, the manual is available [here](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/symbolics/LM-2/Operating_the_Lisp_Machine.pdf) (page 36).

Comment: Archive.org [copy of the *Operating the Lisp machine*](https://web.archive.org/web/20100808213520/http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/symbolics/LM-2/Operating_the_Lisp_Machine.pdf) manual.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The Space Cadet is a keyboard designed for use with Symbolics' [Lisp Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine), and many of the extra keys are specific to that use.

Starting from the bottom row:

- <kbd>Hyper</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>, <kbd>Meta</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> are modifier keys, known as bucky keys; they are equivalent in use to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> on modern keyboards (and to the Windows, context menu, Apple and Option keys). They allow shortcuts to be built using the main keys. You can see their heritage in Emacs, with its many shortcuts involving <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> on modern keyboards). Many Linux systems use the Windows key as <kbd>Super</kbd>.
- <kbd>Top</kbd>, <kbd>Greek</kbd> (or <kbd>Front</kbd>) and <kbd>Shift</kbd> allow the various symbols on the keycaps to be produced. Thus <kbd>M</kbd> on its own produces "m", <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> produces "M", <kbd>Top</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> produces "≥", <kbd>Greek</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> produces "µ" (as indicated on the front of the keycaps). <kbd>Repeat</kbd> allows keys to be repeated — they didn't repeat by default.
- <kbd>Mode Lock</kbd> isn’t used. <kbd>Alt Mode</kbd> was used on [ITS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incompatible_Timesharing_System) and was considered obsolete even when the Space Cadet was designed; it is similar to <kbd>Esc</kbd> on current systems, and echoed “◊” on SAIL terminals or “$” on ASCII terminals. <kbd>Rub Out</kbd> is the ancestor of our <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (erase left). <kbd>Help</kbd> was supposed to be handled by applications for on-line help (but rarely was).
- <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>II</kbd>, <kbd>III</kbd> and <kbd>IV</kbd> were used for quick selection in menus.
- <kbd>Network</kbd>, <kbd>Terminal</kbd> and <kbd>System</kbd> send escapes to specify which part of the system (as a whole) the user wanted to interact with.
- <kbd>Status</kbd> was supposed to ask the system to provide status information for the currently process.
- The thumb and finger keys weren’t used much if at all; the thumb up and down keys may have been used to answer yes/no questions, but that’s not clear at all. [The `KMOUSE` program](https://ml.cddddr.org/info-lispm/msg00302.html) allowed all four keys to be used to move the mouse pointer.
- <kbd>Macro</kbd> was intended to provide a keyboard-based macro system, but it saw little use in practice.
- <kbd>Quote</kbd> allows escaping other keys, so they can be sent rather than interpreted — a bit like the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key on Atari 8-bit keyboards, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> in current shells.
- <kbd>Over Strike</kbd> moves the cursor left without erasing, allowing characters to be superimposed. <kbd>Line</kbd> moved the cursor down a line (line feed).
- The two <kbd>Clear</kbd> keys clear the current input field and the whole screen respectively.
- <kbd>Hold Output</kbd> and <kbd>Stop Output</kbd> provide output flow control (similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>).
- <kbd>Abort</kbd>, <kbd>Break</kbd>, <kbd>Resume</kbd> and <kbd>Call</kbd> provide process and function control; for example <kbd>Call</kbd> suspends the current process on ITS, in a similar fashion to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> in job-capable shells.

With the <kbd>Greek</kbd> key, these keyboards allow all of the [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29) character set to be entered easily. The modifier keys can be combined: <kbd>Greek</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> produces "λ" as you'd expect, and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Greek</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> produces "Λ". Likewise the bucky keys can be combined, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> is meaningful — this is still the case on modern keyboards, the obvious example being <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd>. The Greek-style behaviour lives on too; on my Linux systems with a French keyboard layout, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> produces "ŀ", and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt Gr</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> produces "Ŀ". On the Space Cadet, the modifier keys were specifically laid out so they could be chorded single-handedly using either hand: you could press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> with your left hand, and <kbd>L</kbd> with your right, or vice-versa *e.g.* for <kbd>Q</kbd>.

Holding down both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys and both <kbd>Meta</kbd> keys allowed the system to be rebooted: with those four keys depressed, pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> would warm-boot the system, and <kbd>Rubout</kbd> would cold-boot it.

You'll find more information on [Mike McMahon's page on the Space Cadet](https://web.archive.org/web/20150112030657/http://home.comcast.net/~mmcm/kbd/SpaceCadet.html) and in John Kulp's [design notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910154424/http://home.comcast.net/~mmcm/kbd/lmdoc_kbdpro.3.txt) for the keyboard, and in [the Lisp Machine’s operating manual](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/symbolics/LM-2/Operating_the_Lisp_Machine.pdf) (page 36). Thanks to [Mark](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/4/mark) and [mnem](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/320/mnem) for further information provided in the comments, to [Lars Brinkhoff](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/142/lars-brinkhoff) for finding `KMOUSE`, to [vxid](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/12166/vxid) for finding the operating manual, and to [devon](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/12229/devon) for correcting a number of misattributed keys!

Comment: This is a great list! You get a press of the  key `:)`

Comment: @Laurel thanks, funnily enough I left the thumb keys out! But they weren't used much.

Comment: You can combine the `Greek` and `Shift` modifiers, so `Greek`+`Shift`+`L` produces "Λ", not "λ".

Comment: If I remember correctly you can combine the various modifier keys too.  So for example you could write your program to do something specific when you chord Hyper+Super+Meta+Ctrl+Q, for example.  This makes it possible to type over 8,000 different characters.  And yes, you can still see the legacy of this keyboard in some of the crazy "shortcut" combos in emacs.

Comment: @mnem yes indeed, and the keys were specifically laid out so they could be chorded single-handedly and with either hand. I'll update later to clarify that!

Comment: Gawd... is it possible to plug that thing into a modern PC? And not have the PC's CPU explode in giblets?

Comment: @SF. [Probably](https://github.com/hanshuebner/symbolics-keyboard)! Using a micro-controller (or even a Raspberry Pi–style computer) you can pretty much connect anything to a modern PC.

Comment: If only I could work in the OS and domain designed for this keyboard, every day for the rest of my life. That would be true programmer heaven.

Comment: "The hand keys move the mouse (Control- etc. vary the amount), and the Roman numeral keys act like buttons."
https://ml.cddddr.org/info-lispm/msg00302.html

Comment: I'd imaging Over Strike was like the modrn insert/overwrite toggle. And if you look closely, you can see the Greek key says Front on its front face, ehich is pretty cool.

Comment: The thumb and finger keys are not the ancestors of arrow keys, which we never used even on keyboards which had them.
⟨key⟩ ^X (ASCII) mappings and uses:
⟨RubOut⟩ ^? (DEL) Erase left.
⟨OverStrike⟩ ^H (BS) Move left without erasing, e.g., to superimpose the next character.
⟨Line⟩ ^J (LF) Move down.
⟨Return⟩ ^M (CR) Move all the way left and activate the typed-in command.
⟨AltMode⟩ ^[ (ESC) Echoes as ◊ on SAIL displays or $ on ASCII displays.
⟨Quote⟩ ^Q Quote next key, i.e., treat as a character not a function.
⟨Call⟩ ^Z Suspend ITS process.
⟨Help⟩ Little used.
⟨Mode-Lock⟩ Unused.

Comment: The keyboard was originally used for the MIT Lisp Machine late 70s. When LMI (https://deskthority.net/viewtopic.php?t=19373) and Symbolics commercialized them beginning early 80s, the first batch of their machines still used this keyboard. Symbolics then developed simpler keyboards ( https://deskthority.net/download/file.php?id=47925&sid=01fef7223ad8d02be4c1b2ba9242e204 and https://i.imgur.com/TkO0noAl.jpg ).

Comment: The Mode Lock key is used in Symbolics Genera in a few places. For example the code profiler may collect information which the Mode Lock is on.